# Google Cloud ML Engine: Access Online Prediction Logs

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I just created a model on ML Engine with:

`gcloud ml-engine models create test_model --enable-logging`

I went into the GUI and created a version.  I'm hitting this model for predictions but where do I go in the GUI to find the logs for online predictions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The logs can be found in StackDriver Logging:

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com
- Click on the "hamburger" icon in the top left
- Find the "Logging" option under "STACKDRIVER"
- Click on "Logs" (you can get directly here with a link similar to: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=my_project, just subsituate your actual project name)
- Locate the drop down menu that allows you to select your logs.
- Hover over "Cloud ML Model Version
- Either click the model you're interested in or hover over it, if you want to select a specific version
- (Optional) If selecting a specific version, click on it.

That said, I'll file a feature request to have a link in a more convenient place alongside the model and/or version.

Comment: thanks for the help!  Can you tell me what you mean by "Locate the drop down menu that allows you to select your logs"?  I see a drop down that contains recent Cloud ML jobs and things like `Audited Resource`, `BigQuery`, `Cloud ML Job`, but nothing that looks like it might get me to my currently active model (the one serving predictions)

Comment: That's the right place. Have you sent traffic to the model?